# Is it possible to enter tabular data in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, input

I want to enter table of X and Y values then plot them. I don't want to enter brackets and or commas. Can I prepare grid for myself and them fill it with data in Mathematica, like in Excel?

I found Insert -> Table/Matrix, but how to insert rows columns afterwards?

Comment: If your data is in excel you can `Import` it. If you want to enter your data manually, you can use Insert -> Matrix, choose the right dimension. On windows, `ctrl+,` adds column and `ctrl+enter` adds row

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci great, thanks, and how to delete row/column? And how to learn about it?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html

Comment: @Dims, Select row or column you want to delete and hit delete..

Comment: Same commands for adding column or row in macOS as in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using the menus, you can do the following :

[image]

On Windows :

- Hit Ctrl + ",". It creates a new cell with a 2 boxes grid inside.
- Hit Ctrl + "," as many times as you want to add columns
- Hit Ctrl + Enter to creates new rows
- Filling : "a" Tab "b" Tab etc...
- Then evaluate the cell normally (Shift + Enter)
- You can give a name  to your data by typing "myData=" just before the grid.

Moreover, it is often usefull to create programmatically a pre-filled grid:

[image]

The code `// ToBoxes // (# /. TagBox[x_, ___] :> x &) // RawBoxes` is necessary if you want that the evaluation of the grid gives a List of List (I mean the grid generated by the code `//ToBoxes...RawBoxes` , ie the last grid).